# Write a function that takes an integer n, and compute between 0 and n how many integers contain 5

Tags: javascript

I am trying to solve this question and I know a way to solve it for number of 0s, but I am unable to solve it for number of 5s
I am trying soemthing like this

```
  function findFive(lastNumber){

        var count=1,k;
        if(lastNumber<5)
            return 0;
        else if(lastNumber===5)
            return 1;
        else{

            for(var i=6;i<=lastNumber;i++){
                k=i;
                while(k>0){

                    if(k%5==0 && k%10!==0)
                        count++;
                        k=k/5;
                }
            }
            return count;
        }
    }
```

but this wont work for numbers like 50, 550, 500 etc. So i wanted to know which is the best and efficient way to solve this problem.

Thanks. Any help appreciated

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding exactly what you want. Are you trying to count the amount of fives in a number?

Comment: Are you looking for the character `5` or for multiples of `5`?

Comment: You could simply stringify the number.

Comment: if you are passing the last digit to the `findFive()` function then it's not surprising that wont detect a lastdigit of 0 as a 5

Comment: yes... I am trying to count how many integers contain '5' in a given range. for eg: between 0 and 15, there are 2 occurances etc..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To count the number of integers containing a `5`, in a range from `0...lastNumber`, try something like this:

```
function findFive(lastNumber){
    var count = 0,
        str = lastNumber + '';
    for(var i = 0; i <= lastNumber; i++){
        if((i+'').indexOf('5') !== -1){
            count++;
        }
    } 
    return count;
}
```

Results:

```
findFive(60)     // 15
findFive(550)    // 146
findFive(550746) // 255502
```

Just keep in mind that the larger this number gets, the more time it's going to take to calculate the result.

Comment: I dont want to count number of fives in an integer, i want to find the integers in a given range that contains the number '5'

Comment: I think this is not what the OP is asking for, he wants the amount of numbers which have a 5. for instance: if the input is 60 the numbers with 5 are (5,15,25,35,45,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59) so the function should return 15

Answer (score 1):

We can see a pattern for the total, as we keep increasing digits.

```
1    -- 0
5    -- 1
10   -- 0 * 9   + 10^0 = 1
59   -- 1 * 5   + 10^1    
60   -- 1 *(6-1)+ 10^1
100  -- 1 * 9   + 10^1 = 19
599  -- 19* 5   + 10^2
600  -- 1 *(6-1)+ 10^2
1000 -- 19* 9   + 10^2 = 271
```

with this pattern we can get the results by looking at each of the digits in the number
for example:

```
332    -- 3*19 + 3*1 + 2*0 
984    -- [(9-1)*19 + 100] + [(8-1)*1 + 10] + [4*0]
3943   -- 3*271 + ((8-1)*19 + 100) + 4*1 + 3*0
1543   -- 1*271 + (5*1 +44)
```

then we can write some code.

```
function findFive(n){
    // we'll cast the value to a string, to be able to grab the Most Significant Digit easily
    return _findFive(String(n))["t"]    
}
// helper function. Returns the integer value of the number without 
// the first digit (eg. "3948" returns 948)
function remaining(n){                      
    return n.length > 1 ? parseInt(n.substr(1)) : 0;
}

// Recursive function. Returns the total number of 5s in the range 0 to n, and the multiplier for the next higher digit
function _findFive(n){
    if(n.length == 0) return {t:0,m:0};
    var result = _findFive(n.substr(1));    // get the total from the less significant digits. 
                                            // Also returns the multiplier for the MSD
    var msd = n[0];                         // Most significant digit
    if(msd < 5)         total = msd * result["m"] + result["t"];
    else if(msd == 5)   total = msd * result["m"] + remaining(n) + 1;
    else                total = (msd-1) * result["m"] + Math.pow(10,n.length-1) + result["t"];

    var multiplier = result["m"]* 9 + Math.pow(10,n.length-1);  // calculate multiplier for next higher digit
    return {t:total,m:multiplier}   
}
```

This code will solve the problem in log(n) time. It's not necessary to process each of the numbers in the range (O(n) time) to get the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could make it a string and search on that. Something like,

```
function findFive(upperBound) {
  var count = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < upperBound; ++i) {
    if (i.toString().match(/5/)) {
      ++count;
    }
  }
  return count;
}
```

To see if this is more efficient than a number parsing approach you should try and benchmark them both.